# How to change computed image src property to another one based on the current page loaded, using Vue 3 and Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I've trying to solve this problem related to dynamic changes to UI, firstly trying to do with native vanilla JS, but adapted to Nuxt 3 and Vue further. Though, I'm having problems with function recognition and the methods `setAttribute` using computed properties.

How can I make the `src` of the image a computed property then change it based on my current "route.path"? I'm struggling with the modern syntax.

Current script:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import {reactive, computed} from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const imagem = ref();


onMounted(() => {
    changeImg();
    
})
const properties = reactive({
    home: "~/assets/img/fire-hor.gif",
    alt: "Logo do Barnabé",
    banda: "~/assets/img/bonfire.gif",
    
})

const enhangeImg = computed(() => {
    function changeImg(){

        var PAGINA = route.path;
        if (typeof route.path !== "undefined") {
            if (PAGINA === '/') {
                imagem.setAttribute('src', properties.home);
            }
            else if (PAGINA === '/banda') {
                imagem.setAttribute('src', properties.banda);
            }
        return changeImg();
        }
    }
    return enhangeImg = changeImg(); 
})

</script>
```

Current template:

```
<template >
    <div class="barna-logo">
        <img ref="imagem"  id="image" 
        :src="(enhangeImg)" :alt="(properties.alt)" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Dir. hierarchy:

[image: directory]

Current error lines:

[image: error + console]

I've tried to use logic of vue router, computed and `onMounted` to change `src` from "fire-hor.gif" to "bonfire.gif" if it's /index page or /banda page, but I'm confused with the new Nuxt syntax.

I know I'm a begginer and have a couple logic errors within my code too. Pls guide me!

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77848758/edit) your  [error message as text instead of an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing a `computed` value with a `function`. The computed method's return is a `Proxy` object which gives you a `value` property containing the resulting value of the computation.

What you want instead, is to watch the change of the `route` in Nuxt 3, and then respond accordingly:

```js
const properties = reactive({
    home: "~/assets/img/fire-hor.gif",
    alt: "Logo do Barnabé",
    banda: "~/assets/img/bonfire.gif",
    
})
const imageSrc = ref(properties.home);
const route = useRoute();

watch(route, (routeChange) => {
    const path = routeChange.path;

    if (PAGINA === '/') {
        imageSrc.value = properties.home;
    }

    if (PAGINA === '/banda') {
        imageSrc.value = properties.banda
    }
}, {deep: true, immediate: true})
```

Of course, bind the value of `imageSrc` to your `<img` element:

```html
<img :src="imageSrc" :alt="properties.alt" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. I'm going to invest my time studying about those terms now.